# Solve the following by converting it to Clairaut's equation, $(x^2+y^2)(1+p)^2-2(x+y)(1+p)(x+py)+(x+py)^2=0$, where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We were taught Clairaut's equation and the procedure to solve them. It looked really simple! But then,  I  am really having some trouble, to solve problems of these sort:

Solve the following differential equation by converting it to Clairaut's  equation, $(x^2+y^2)(1+p)^2-2(x+y)(1+p)(x+py)+(x+py)^2=0$(, where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$)

I tried conversions of the type $x^2=u$ and $y^2=v.$  But this wasn't precisely very helpful. I tried multiplying throughout by $y$ and then using the transformation $y^3=u$, but again, it was no use. Similarly,  I tried many ways but it all seems like throwing stones in the dark and I gave up.

I want to learn, if there are any way to guess which transformations will gurantee a conversion to the required Clairaut's equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $u=x+y$ and $v=x^2+y^2$

Comment: The problem is, I have never worked with transformations involving both the variables. It would be really helpful, if you consider, how to proceed.

Comment: $\begin{align}&\frac{dv}{du}(=q)=\frac{2(x+py)}{1+p}\\&\implies p=\frac{2x-q}{q-2y}\end{align}$

Comment: Put the value and simplify.

Comment: Woah! Things went so smoothly. But all in all, what was the motivation behind this transformation? Is it from your probably long experience of working with ODEs ?